# Search Apple App store by genre with iOS/Obj-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store, itunes-store

How would you use Obj-c to search the Apple App store to do the following...

1. Return the details of the top 100 in the games overall category or a
   specific games category
2. Return the details of a specific games in the games category

Anyone?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, as far as I know you have two methods to search the App Store:

1. [Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html);
2. [RSS feed generator](http://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator/).

There are many differences between those but the most relevant for your example is that with the [Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) you cannot sort the results as they come sorted by relevance and it requires always a search term. The [RSS feed generator](http://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator/) already has Top Free, Top Paid and Top Grossing categories for you.

Given this I'm going to start answering your question for the [RSS feed generator](http://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator/).

1. You use the [RSS feed generator](http://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator/) to generate feeds like this for the top 100 free games in the US store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=100/genre=6014/xml;

   - Take a loot at [this link](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/genre-mapping.html) to get games sub genres;
2. You use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) library to parse the RSS which already includes the app details.

   - You may use the `initWithContentsOfUrl:` method of NSXMLParser;
   - A quick how-to for this part can be found [here](http://blog.merrycode.com/how-to-parse-rss-feeds-using-nsxmlparser-in-objective-c/).

You can also use [StoreKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/_index.html) to get the details of the apps by their ID or show a modal view controller with a specific app but that will require an extra network request.

---

For the sake of completeness I'll also cover how you can use the [Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

1. Use the [Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) to create a URL that describes your search:

   - A URL like this allow you to search for apps with that matches "angry birds" - [https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=angry+birds&media=software](https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=angry%20birds&media=software).
2. Process the results using [NSJSONSerialization library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html). That already includes the app details.

   - Take a loot at [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) on how to use the [NSJSONSerialization library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In the end, as @Numan said, this two methods accomplish different things. You said you wanted to have the top 100 games from a specific category and also said you needed to search for a specific game.

You can use my descriptions to create one class that interacts with the App Store in these two ways and return an object defined by you that describes an app (or an array of objects).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. What if I want to find a specific game though? then the only option would be to use the search API correct? and if that's the case is it possible to do everything you just described by using the RSS feed, but with the search API? with the RSS Feed I could not see any way to search for games or game genres on the app store

Comment: You won't be able to search for anything using the RSS Feed. The data in the RSS feed is preset by Apple which you can just filter in limited ways. If you want to look up a game, Search API would be the way to go. The search API depends on a keyword to search and as described sorts the result according to relevance to the search term so getting a top 100 out of it would be a challenge. The best thing to do is to use the proper method for a given problem and not generalize in this case

Comment: I think the only thing missing there for using the Search API is getting you a tutorial of how to use NSJSONSerialization. Here is one I found that makes use of background fetching: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: Thanks for all of that. Ok so basically, I have to use both approaches? for the top 100 etc, I grab the XML from the feed, and for specific games the search API? Any chance of you adding in an example search URL string for a game? say Angry birds? because I still can't see how you search within the genre of games with the Search API, it seems not to include the App store.

Comment: Ok, I've been trying to do a search by genre but I couldn't. This should've work but got no results: http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=6014&attribute=genreIndex&media=software. If this worked you could do a search by name with a URL like I showed you and another one by genre and then matching. This is sub-optimal and but is the best I was able to come up with. And still I couldn't make it work. You can also search within your results and filtering the genreIDs you get. Still a dirty solution.

Comment: Are we sure you can use the search API to search the app store at all? "software" might just refer to OSX, and not iOS ?

Comment: Yes. When you search something like this: https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=rovio&media=software&attribute=softwareDeveloper&entity=software. You are only searching for iOS apps. You can also use entity=macSoftware or entity=iPadSoftware but as far as I know you cannot combine them to search in all.

Comment: Thanks. But you still couldn't get that search to return any results? why would that be?

Comment: Don't know why. For problems on their documentation one should go to their forums. I did a quick search but didn't find anything related to searching by genre but you should add a question there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add another question here, although interestingly there does seem to be one already with no answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access this info by RSS, look here http://www.apple.com/rss/

Also you can generate RSS feed http://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator/

Comment: Thanks I'm aware of the RSS feeds, but that doesn't help me with my specific question, also I don't know if I have to use the search API, or the RSS feeds, or how to search as in the examples I asked above and how to do it in obj-c/iOS.