# Use the Apple Search API to search by genre?

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store

Is it possible to use the Apple Search API to search by genre ? I'm thinking specifically games in the app store. Using Obj-c.

As has been pointed out in the comments of this question...

[Search Apple App store by genre with iOS/Obj-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833521/search-apple-app-store-by-genre-with-ios-obj-c/13877257#13877257)

There seems to be a problem with trying to search by genre, so I'm looking for answers which of examples of that actually working, not just links to the docs.

Comment: From the Search API documentation, I can't see a way to do that. I'll update my answer if I find something

Answer (score 7):

It's not actually documented on the [Search API documentation](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html), but you can add a `genreId` parameter to the search URL and it restricts the search to a particular genre.

If you look at the JSON returned from [a search for "Yelp"](https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yelp&country=us&entity=software), there are 4 interesting things:

```
"genreIds":["6005", "6001"]
"genres":["Social Networking", "Weather"]
"primaryGenreName":"Social Networking"
"primaryGenreId":6005
```

Adding `&genreId=6001` to a URL will find apps in the US in the "Weather" category. I'm using the search term "Check" in the URL.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Check&country=us&entity=software&genreId=6001
```

Because it's not documented, you can't rely on it working forever. You may also be able to use the `primaryGenreName` as a parameter, I didn't try that. You'll have to figure out what numbers correspond to what categories too.

Comment: Genre IDs for iTunes are documented here:  http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/genre-mapping.html

Comment: At the time of writing `primaryGenreId` seems to be the only working parameter .

Comment: hmm...link from 7 years ago doesn't work anymore? Plan B - scrape this page for all the links and get the genre ID's from the end of each URL ...https://apps.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36

Answer (score 4):

The Search API is documented here: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

You can use [this link](http://itunes.apple.com/rss) to generate an RSS Feed of your liking. Without knowing too much about how you intend to use it, I would suggest looking at these two solutions and using the best one that suits your needs.

Comment: Do you have the new link for this page, it seems does not work anymore or removed